# Fill area between lines in R (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to visualize some data in R, where i have three diffrent groups (LH) and a sucess rate depending on propHarv. Now when I plot it as a line graph it looks not really nice...

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=propHarv, y=success, colour=LH))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()
```

Line PLot.
[image: Line PLot]

So i thought i could make a nicer graph by filling the area between the red and the blue line by using geom_area

```
 ggplot(data, aes(x=propHarv, y=success)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=LH,stat="density"),colour="black",alpha=0.6) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgrey", "darkolivegreen2","grey"))+
  theme_bw()
```

Area Plot.
[image: area plot]

but what i get is a stacked plot. But I also want to just fill the area between the red and the blue line.(i know i could set the third colour just as white but Im sure there is a nicer way...

Also i know that geom_ribbon might work, but my data is organised diffrently, do I have to reorganize the data?

Additionally I would like to shade the area where all of the curves are 0 and the area where all of the curves are one is that possible in addition?

Many thanks for your help!!

cheers

Nina

Comment: can you dput your data?

Comment: `geom_ribbon` shouldn't require rearrangement; you just need to set the `ymin` and `ymax` aesthetics, e.g. `geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = 0, ymax = ..y..))`

Comment: Try using a position other than `"stack"` (depends on your data, probably `"identity"`